# How to upload a file to amazon s3 and get link for it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to upload an image to Amazon S3 and get a link for the file(Using ASIHTTPRequest for amazon s3). For now I have done the following(my questions are actually in code):

```
- (void) uploadAnImageToS3 {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        [ASIS3Request setSharedSecretAccessKey:@"*****here I put my secretkey*****"];
        [ASIS3Request setSharedAccessKey:@"*****here I put my key*****"];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageToPost)];
        NSString * key = @"aKey"
        ASIS3ObjectRequest *request = [ASIS3ObjectRequest PUTRequestForData:imageData withBucket:@"theBucketName" key:key];
        [request setShouldCompressRequestBody:YES];
        [request startSynchronous];


        if (![request error]) {
            //Here I should share a link for the put file, how do I get it? Is there any response from s3?
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"%@",[[request error] localizedDescription]);
        }
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopActivity) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
    [pool release];
}
```

[image: I can't figure out why respString content is not accessible]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okey, I've managed to do it myself :)
Firstly you should set an access policy which is the property of PUT request

requestForPUTSmth.accessPolicy = ASIS3AccessPolicyPublicReadWrite;

The link for the file is composed in such way:

NSString * linkString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@.s3.amazonaws.com/%@", bucket, key];

Where bucket - is the name of your folder on S3 and Key is the name of file. That's it.

Comment: Oh, I hate downvotes without comments! :( If you are so clever why didn't you answer the question ??

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions in order:

1. The `key` variable you declare there is the name the file will take in S3. Files are identified by their keys within buckets, and keys must be unique - think of them kind of like filenames, but you only get one level of folders (the buckets).
2. Once your request has completed (the `startSynchronous` method returns), it looks like you can access the `responseData` or `responseString` attributes of the request to get any return data that S3 has provided.

Comment: Should I create a bucket per file or I can use one bucket for many files?

Comment: You can (and should) use one bucket for many files, but each file needs its own unique key in that bucket.

Comment: ok, understood. Please tell me do I need to provide any additional information besides SharedSecretAccessKey and SharedAccessKey. I'm trying to get list of buckets but i'm getting an error
    ASIS3ServiceRequest *requestOfBuckets = [ASIS3ServiceRequest serviceRequest];
    [requestOfBuckets startSynchronous];
    if (![request error]) {
        NSArray *buckets = [requestOfBuckets buckets]; // An array of ASIS3Bucket objects
        NSLog(@"buckets:%@", buckets);
    }

Comment: I've already fixed that error but still cannot compose a link. Could you please tell me why I cannot nslog a response? It is coming well and of course exists but I can't look at its contents in debuger. I'll try to post a screenshot